# Build 32bit on 64 bit Linux using an automake configure script?

Tags: autotools, configure, automake

I'm using a 64bit system but want a set of 32bit binaries. What options must I pass to a configure script to generate a 32bit/x86 makefile?

Comment: Plus one. I'm trying to build Git for Solaris. `uname -m` returns `i86pc`. All but one of the 10 or so dependent libraries misdetected the platform. Only OpenSSL correctly identified it as x86_64.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Passing the following argument to configure script allowed me to build the 32bit library on 64bit Linux

```
./configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu CFLAGS=-m32 CXXFLAGS=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me :( Please help me at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780319/cant-build-32bit-wine-on-64bit-linux

Comment: It didn't work for me when trying to build a library. It gave me the message `configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables`.

Comment: This answer is incomplete, which is why sometimes you can get the  "compiler cannot create executables" error. See my answer in this same thread

Answer (score 54):

Jack's answer is incomplete.

You need compiler/libc support for 32-bit compilation. In some distros like Ubuntu, what you need to do is install packages `gcc-multilib` and/or `g++-multilib`:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```

Then you can call configure as you said, specifyiong a 32-bit host and passing 32-bit compilation flags:

```
./configure --host=i686-linux-gnu "CFLAGS=-m32" "CXXFLAGS=-m32" "LDFLAGS=-m32"
```

If you do not have multilib installed, you will get an error like `configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables` when passing the `-m32` flag.

Comment: Some programs compile 32-bit on amd64 by default (eg. wine,) possibly in addition to 64-bit and should be able to find multilib if installed. Doesn't seem to be the case for OP. Also, Jack was right about one thing - it should be `--build`, not `--host`. `--host` should be used if and only if you are building a compiler. It still works because there is plenty of people who don't RTFM and write scripts that use `--host` instead of `--build`, and the autotools people have broken enough things already.

Comment: the *-multilib packages doesn't exist anymore in Debian stable.

Comment: I still see `g++-multilib` in Debian Stretch. As well as that, you will need to enable 32-bit runtime libraries, as documented at https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO. The commands at the bottom of that page `dpkg --add-architecture i386; apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386` are a good starting point. You can install extra libraries as needed now, for example to build something that requires SSL, you can `apt-get install libssl-dev:i386`.

Comment: @JonathanBaldwin  `./configure --help` says (for a script generated by autoconf):

`System types:
  --build=BUILD     configure for building on BUILD [guessed]
  --host=HOST       cross-compile to build programs to run on HOST [BUILD]`

Answer (score 8):

I had better success by setting a custom compiler instead.  This way all the configure tests, even the ones using custom CFLAGS, worked correctly:

```
./configure CC="gcc -m32" CXX="g++ -m32"
```

You still need 32-bit versions of all the libraries the application uses of course, so any errors about missing libraries are referring to the 32-bit ones.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming gcc/g++:

```
CPPFLAGS=-m32 ./configure ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The configure script still sets the  build system type and host system type to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu. Do you know how to override these?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to the things described above would be (if you have) to use a dedicated x86 compiler. The configure line would then be like this (I named the x86-tools after the pattern "<toolname>-x86"):

```
CC="/path/to/c/compiler/gcc-x86" CXX="path/to/cpp/compiler/g++-x86" LD="path/to/linker/ld-x86" ./configure
```