# Can't build 32bit Wine on 64bit linux

Tags: linux

I'm trying to do this:
[Build 32bit on 64 bit Linux using an automake configure script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261909/build-32bit-on-64-bit-linux-using-a-configure-script)
Doesn't work for me :(
Compileing wine. I found this in config.log:

```
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "Wine"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "wine"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.5.19"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "Wine 1.5.19"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "wine-devel@winehq.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.winehq.org"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
```

Configuration fails with: `Cannot build a 32-bit program, you need to install 32-bit development libraries.`

Answer (score 13):

```
apt-get install gcc-multilib libasound2-dev:i386 libgsm1-dev:i386 libjpeg8-dev:i386 liblcms2-dev:i386 libldap2-dev:i386 libmpg123-dev:i386 libopenal-dev:i386 libv4l-dev:i386 libx11-dev:i386 libxinerama-dev:i386 libxml2-dev:i386 zlib1g-dev:i386
```

and

```
apt-get install libcapi20-dev:i386 libcups2:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libfontconfig:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgnutls26:i386 libgphoto2-2:i386 libncurses5:i386 libosmesa6:i386 libsane:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxi6:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386
```

got me past X error.

Answer (score 11):

To build 32-bit wine on 64-bit machine, you can use LXC (Linux Containers) which is an operating-system-level virtualization environment for running multiple isolated Linux systems. It's the easiest solution so far, as Linux (such as Ubuntu or Debian) makes building 32-bit wine hard because the 64-bit system doesn't come with a full set of 32-bit development libraries (See: [Bug #990982](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/freetype/+bug/990982)).

So the basic approach to compile both 32-bit and 64-bit wine is:

1. Build 64-bit wine
2. Build 32-bit tools in lxc
3. Build 32-bit wine in lxc, referring to the 64-bit wine and 32-bit tools 1. built in the previous steps
4. Install 32-bit wine
5. Install 64-bit wine

On the page [Building Biarch (Shared WoW64) Wine On Ubuntu](http://wiki.winehq.org/BuildingBiarchWineOnUbuntu) we can read the following instructions:

1. Install the 64-bit prerequisites:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get build-dep wine
   ```
2. Build 64-bit wine:

   ```
   mkdir $HOME/wine64
   cd $HOME/wine64
   ../wine-git/configure --enable-win64
   make -j4
   ```
3. Install lxc:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install lxc
   ```
4. Create a 32-bit container named "my32bitbox" using the Ubuntu
   template and bind your home directory to the /home directory in the
   container:

   ```
   sudo lxc-create -t ubuntu -n my32bitbox -- --bindhome $LOGNAME -a i386
   ```
5. Copy the apt configuration from the host to the lxc container:

   ```
   sudo cp -R /etc/apt /var/lib/lxc/my32bitbox/rootfs/etc
   ```
6. Start the container; at the console login prompt it gives you, log
   in with your username and password.

   ```
   sudo lxc-start -n my32bitbox
   ```
7. Now you're inside the container, in your real home directory. If you
   are not in the container (you do not have the prompt
   username@my32bitbox), then open a new terminal and:

   ```
   sudo lxc-attach -n my32bitbox
   login yourusername+password
   ```
8. Now, you are in the container. Do an out-of-tree build of Wine as
   normal, just to get the tools. You'll have to install all the needed
   prerequisites first. For instance:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install python-software-properties git-core
   sudo apt-get build-dep wine
   mkdir $HOME/wine32-tools
   cd $HOME/wine32-tools
   ~/wine-git/configure
   make -j4
   ```
9. Still inside the container, do it again, this time pointing to the
   64-bit build for data, and the 32-bit tools build for tools:

   ```
   mkdir $HOME/wine32
   cd $HOME/wine32
   ~/wine-git/configure --with-wine64=$HOME/wine64 --with-wine-tools=$HOME/wine32-tools
   make -j4
   ```
10. Still inside the container, install the 32-bit wine to force the
    last little bit of building:

    ```
    cd $HOME/wine32
    sudo make install
    ```
11. While still inside the container, shut it down:

    ```
    sudo shutdown -h now
    ```

    This drops you back out into your real machine. Next, you need to
    remove all existing Wine packages. You can do this from the command
    line but it's probably easier with aptitude or one of the GUI
    package management tools. You will need wine-mono, wine-gecko, and
    optionally winetricks for your compiled version of wine. However,
    these packages may depend on the existing wine installation which
    may force you to remove them.
12. Install the newly built wine into your real machine:

    ```
    cd $HOME/wine32
    sudo make install
    cd $HOME/wine64
    sudo make install
    ```

    Warning: When you install a locally built version of Wine, the
    package management system will not know it exists since it did not
    come from a package. Thus it is possible to later break its
    dependencies or install a conflicting version of wine without a
    warning from the package management tools. You can prevent this by
    creating a package or by blocking conflicting packages with
    apt-pinning by setting "Pin-Priority: -1" for the packages.
13. Next, install Mono, Gecko, and optionally winetricks if you had to
     remove their packages because of a dependency on a conflicting wine
     package.

Notes:

- Many of the above commands require root privileges. Your user account needs to have access to root via `sudo` or you need to switch to a user account.
- It's not necessary to remove your distro version and 'install' your compiled versions (32bit, 64bit) You simply need to invoke your personal version of wine appropriate for the Windows app. For example: `~/wine32/wine32 ~/.wine/path_to_winapp/my_app`.

Comment: configure doesnt finds the wine-tools in 32

Answer (score 3):

What worked to some extent for me on Debian Wheezy:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
```

to enable installation from the i386 repos

```
apt-get install ia32-libs libc6-dev-i386 lib32z1-dev lib32bz2-dev
```

to install the 32 bit libs. I'm actually still having trouble with X libs:

```
configure: error: X 32-bit development files not found. Wine will be built
without X support, which probably isn't what you want. You will need
to install 32-bit development packages of Xlib/Xfree86 at the very least.
Use the --without-x option if you really want this.
```

but it's technically optional.

Answer (score 2):

you may solve the X error:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. Wine builds for 32-bit by default even on 64-bit systems (since it has to run 32-bit Windows programs.) It also builds a 64-bit Wine at the same time. If you want to disable that, configure it with:

```
./configure --disable-win64
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but still doesn't work. I edited my question and added the terminal output. What libraries you think I should install?

Comment: @m93a You need 32-bit development libraries for all Wine dependencies. Like libalsa, mesa, x11, and many more. I don't know the full list.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you use Ubuntu x64 which now supports multi-architecture. In other words on a 64 bit system you can build only Wine-x64 version. Building 32bit Wine on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 seems to buggy as for now.

So just run:

```
./configure --enable-win64
```

Answer (score 0):

The Wine wiki has an easy way to install the needed 32bit development libraries on a 64bit system, using chroot: [http://wiki.winehq.org/WineOn64bit](https://web.archive.org/web/20150730054943/http://wiki.winehq.org/WineOn64bit)

Comment: That link now appears to be dead.  The most relevant page may possibly now be https://wiki.debian.org/Wine