# wxWidgets cross-compile - error: size of array ‘_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_0’ is negative

Tags: c++, linux, cross-compiling, wxwidgets, glib

I am trying to compile static wxWidgets 3.1 Libraries for 32 bit Linux on a 64 bit Linux machine.

My configuration is the following:

```
../configure "CFLAGS=-m32" "CXXFLAGS=-m32" "LDFLAGS=-m32" --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --disable-shared --enable-unicode
make
```

The library starts to build but then halfway through I get this error:

```
In file included from /usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h:9:0,
             from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:32,
             from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
             from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
             from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:28,
             from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:23,
             from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:28,
             from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:28,
             from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:26,
             from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:30,
             from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
             from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
             from ../src/common/utilscmn.cpp:92:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h: In function ‘gboolean 
_GLIB_CHECKED_ADD_U64(guint64*, guint64, guint64)’:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:142:29: error: size of array ‘_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_0’ is negative
   __attribute__((__unused__))
                         ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:232:120: note: in expansion of 
macro ‘G_GNUC_UNUSED’
#define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE 
(_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] 
G_GNUC_UNUSED

^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:423:3: note: in expansion of macro 
‘G_STATIC_ASSERT’
   G_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof (unsigned long long) == sizeof (guint64));
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:29632: corelib_utilscmn.o] Error 1
```

I notice that the error mentions glib and gtk-2.0. Am I missing a variant of these packages or is my configuration wrong? I believe that my configuration should be correct. Is there special wxWidgets specific options that I am missing in my `configure`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build 32bit on 64 bit Linux using an automake configure script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261909/build-32bit-on-64-bit-linux-using-an-automake-configure-script)

Comment: I think that answer is flawed. There must be some controversy on the difference between --host and --build. [What's the difference of `./configure` option `--build`, `--host` and `--target`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139403/whats-the-difference-of-configure-option-build-host-and-target)

Comment: You're right. That's the most voted answer to the 'possible duplicate' question that is wrong.

Comment: OK, I've found the problem I think. `usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h` is being included instead of `/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h`. I have no idea why though. I made a link to the 32bit header and am not having an error anymore. I would think that configure would set the right headers though, right?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point of cross compiling. Have you tried passing -m32 to CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS? CC and CXX are made for the compiler, not compiler flags, so maybe these don't get passed over. I don't think you need CC or CXX here, configure will detect the compiler it needs based on the host/build combination.

Comment: Fore reference, details about how to call configure for cross compiling are here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Configure-Terms.html

Comment: Tried with `../configure "CFLAGS=-m32" "CXXFLAGS=-m32" "LDFLAGS=-m32" --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --disable-shared --enable-unicode`. Same error.

Comment: @Logan, in the last command can you switch `--host` and `--build`?

Comment: @Igor, when I swap `--host` and `--build` it compiles what seems to be 32 bit library binaries but stops midway with the same error.

Comment: @Logan, you could try to send an email to wx-dev ML. Or create a thread or wx forum before that. Just because wx forum has more people and you could get faster help there.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for the answer, it seems that the best method of cross compiling for 32 bit Linux on 64 bit Linux is to use a chroot build environment. This is apparently what many developers do.

There are some good instructions  [on Github](https://github.com/JdeRobot/JdeRobot/wiki/Create-a-chrooted-environment).