# How can I cross compile from an x86-64 system a program that will run on a i386 architecture?

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling, configure

I need to cross compile an application (written in C) using GNU autoconf/automake, but I cannot find which specific parameter values I have to pass to .configure to make it happen.

The system on which I'm compiling has an x86-64 architecture while the system on which the executable will run has an i386 architecture.

Googleing I found that I need to run

```sh
./configure --host=<cross-compiler for i386 architecture> --build=<my-system-architecture>
```

Is that right? Where can I find the information necessary to run correctly this command (i.e. parameter's values)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit linux machine with gcc/cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272357/how-to-compile-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-linux-machine-with-gcc-cmake)

Comment: Hi, it's actually easier than a "cross-compile" ... This question is nicely answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261909/build-32bit-on-64-bit-linux-using-an-automake-configure-script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build 32bit on 64 bit Linux using an automake configure script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261909/build-32bit-on-64-bit-linux-using-an-automake-configure-script)

Comment: Hm, overlooked: Do you possibly intend not only to compile for different architecture variant, but OS as well (e. g. windows on linux machine)? *Then* you'd really need to do a cross compile...